# Can I use flux core wire in a MIG welder that was designed to use argon gas?

Tags: wire

My friend gave me a MIG welder that has normal wire with the Gas attachment.
I was trying to get argon gas cylinder but had more trouble then expected.
Now I'm thinking of just buying flux core wire and not connecting argon gas at all.

Can I use flux core wire in a MIG welder that was designed to use argon gas?

Comment: Yes flux core will work as well as much cheaper co2, forming glass from welding shops is cheaper than argon or helium . the main difference is with flux core if you need additional passes you need to remove the flux a thick normally black layer of "slang".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that will work fine.  Flux core is sometimes used in MIG welders even when gas is available.  For example, flux core will work in windy conditions that would blow away shielding gas.  Also, flux core often gives somewhat better penetration than gas shielded wire.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can...

HOWEVER! You must use **Electrode Negative.**

If you can give the model/brand, then this will be easier to describe how to get it into this functionality.

It *may* not support this. If you do not use electrode negative, you will get more splatter.

Comment: good point, how do I change the settings so it's electrode negative?

Comment: As stated in my answer, I need the model and brand.